# How to check key submission Asp classic

Tags: post

I'm trying to pass a key to my web service , for more security ,
Like in PHP :

```
if $_POST['Key']="sdcksl":
show content 
end if
```

how can i pass a hiden key to my function ??

Comment: if Request.Form["key"] = "sdcksl" then

Comment: thank u , and how to test it ??

Comment: Won't the content show if it works?

Comment: ive made a function it doesnt show anything,how can i give it the right key to show the content , ?key=dkdjsh  in my url doesnt work ...

Comment: Request.Form["key"] gets the value of a posted item. On the url you want Request.QueryString["key"]